# lxml - Remove element if grand children have text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

So I'm trying to remove element (data) if its subElement value have text `"1"`.
I did some research found how to remove element value, but I have no idea how to remove the grandparent of the element.
I know I can find text by searching this way and then remove element, but that's all I could find.

```
e = root.xpath('.//value[text()="1"]')
e.getParent().remove
```

My XML document looks like this:

```xml
<root>
  <Data>
    <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
    <EMail>email@email.com</EMail>
    <Number>123</Number>
    <delete>
      <value>0</value>
    </delete>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
    <EMail>some@email.com</EMail>
    <delete>
      <value>1</value>
    </delete>
    <Number>456</Number>
  </Data>
</root>
```

Expect result:

```xml
<root>
  <Data>
    <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
    <EMail>email@email.com</EMail>
    <Number>123</Number>
    <delete>
    <value>0</value>
    </delete>
  </Data>
</root>
```

Basically i want to remove element data if element's value contains specific text.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/) (sibling to XPath), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files into other XML. Python's [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module in addition to  running XPath 1.0 can also run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Removes entire Data node with delete child value equal to 1 -->
  <xsl:template match="Data[delete/value='1']"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** *(no `for` loops or `if` logic)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
xml = et.parse('input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('xslt_script.xsl')

# TRANSFORM INPUT 
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    
result = transform(xml)

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an element you need its parent. In this case, the parent of `Data` is `root` (which also happens to be the root element).

Instead of selecting `value`, use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) to select `Data` and remove it from `root` like so...

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for data in tree.xpath("./Data[delete/value='1']"):
    root.remove(data)

print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

**Print Output**

```xml
<root>
  <Data>
    <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
    <EMail>email@email.com</EMail>
    <Number>123</Number>
    <delete>
      <value>0</value>
    </delete>
  </Data>
</root>
```

If I need to remove an element, I hardly ever use `getparent()`; I select the parent specifically. If I need to do more complicated transforms, I use XSLT like suggested by Parfait.